# Get exact number of facebook posts/shares/likes during a period

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm wondering how can I can get exact number of facebook posts/shares/likes during a period, regarding I do a request for a week before and the number of shares/likes could have evolved.

I'm using graph facebook API with request like this :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[id page]/posts?access_token=[token]&fields=id,from,story,name,caption,type,status_type,object_id,created_time,updated_time,shares,likes,comments&since=[timestamp_bebinning_week_before]&until=[timestamp_end]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to count via the Graph API. You'll have to produce the counts yourself by comparing the results from certain timeframes.